# Representations of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be an $F$-vector space, and let $f:G\to GL(V)$, where $G$ is a group. For $g\in G$, how can we show that if $G$ is abelian then the eigenspace of $f(g)$ is a $G$-invariant space?

Moreover, suppose now that $G$ is abelian, and that $F$ is an algebraically closed field. What can we observe about the irreducible representations of $G$? Can we say anything about their orders? Thanks for any help.

Comment: If $G$ is a finite abelian group, then all its irreducible representations are of dimension $1;$ as to infinite groups, I am not familiar with them.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $G$ is abelian, let $V_c$ be the eigenspace of $f(g)$ associated to $c$. For every $g'\in G$, and $x\in V_c, f(g)(f(g')(x))=f(gg')(x)=f(g'g)(c)=f(g')(f(g)(x))=f(g')(cx)=cf(g')(x)$.

Suppose that $F$ is algebraically closed and $V$ is irreducible, for every $g$, $V_c$ is a submodule, thus $V_c=V$.

Comment: So basically your second line says that for an irreducible representation $f$, the eigenspace of $f(g)$ is just the entire $FG$-module that affords $f$?